# Cost of a round-based distributed algorithm

Tags: complexity-theory, distributed-computing

I have a round-based distributed algorithm for a network on n nodes.

I know that the cost (in terms of resource usage) of a round is O(n). However, I do not know the number of rounds, basically they can be repeated till the end of time (infinity).

So what will be the cost of the algorithm? can we say that it is O(n)?

Answer (score 0):

You're not clear on what you're trying to evaluate the big O of. If you mean "Distribute n tasks to a cluster of size n in a round robin fashion" then that would be O(n). If you mean "Distribute the next task in a round robin fashion" then you only need to find the next node, which can be done in O(1).

If you have some other algorithm with which you intend to use a round robin distribution as part of it, you can't determine the big O for that algorithm by looking at this portion alone.